# duplicate entry for key primary in mysql insert 

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am getting disturbing errors due to issues on primary keys and inserting values to table part of my code is here....

In the table I have 3 columns userName, userPwd and userId(auto_incremented primary key)

```
    public boolean addUserBean(UserBean ub)
        {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement prepar = null;


            boolean flag = false;
            String sql = "insert into admin values(?,?)";

            if (hasUser(ub.getUserName()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            try
            {
                prepar = conn.prepareStatement(sql,prepar.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                prepar.setString(1, ub.getUserName());
                prepar.setString(2, ub.getUserPwd());
                int result = prepar.executeUpdate();
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally{

            if (prepar != null) {
                try {
                    prepar.close();
                } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {
                }
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {
                }
            }
}

            return flag;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be manually inserting values into auto increment field. Just leave it out of insert query alltogether.

```
String sql = "insert into admin(userName, userPwd) values(?,?)";
```

the correct auto incremented value will be insseted automatically.

---

Added after more details from OP:

if MySQL complains that Field 'userId' doesn't have a default value then what you told us about your table is wrong, and column userId is not in fact defined as auto increment

Comment: now am getting the error "SEVERE: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'userId' doesn't have a default value" after doing that. please help i want to finish school by april!

Comment: should i add the setter ub.getLong(3,ub.getUserId()); in the rs.next... or should i ignore it

Comment: how about providing your database schema?

Comment: id MySQL complains that `Field 'userId' doesn't have a default value` then what you told us about your table is wrong, and column `userId` is not in fact defined as auto increment

Comment: thanks a bunch guys..... i didnt check the autoincrement now i have... thanks again @Mchl  please the other Q i have posted. be blessed